# Postgresql 9.6 functions argument casting int to string

Tags: oracle, postgresql, casting

I have a function in my postgresql database that get as an argument text : 
func1 (arg1 text);

I summon it many times somethimes with strings as arguments and some times as interger. I know that in oracle we can send int as an argument to a function that get string argument. Is it possible in postgresql ? I must use casting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you do not have the same automatic casting like you have in Oracle. Instead, you have to cast explicitely:

```
select func1(134::text);
```

Comment: There isnt any way to enable auto casting or something like that ?

Comment: No that I am aware of; but you can create a second function, same name, different parameter type, that calls the original one: `create function func1(double precision) returns xxx as 'select func1(arg1::text)' language sql;`

Comment: Yes I realized that, I searched for a solution that might help me handle many data types. Well, Thanks !

Comment: You can enable implicit cast in PostgreSQL. This will work: `CREATE CAST (int AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;`

Comment: Wow, I wish I had known that 2 years earlier!

Comment: Now after the casting of all those types and timzeone I get error  operator is not unique: unknown || bigint, FUNC